# leaflet pixioverlay how can i move marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, pixi.js

can any body please tell me how can i move marker with series of points coordinates by leaflet PIXIOVERLAY.
i am new for using pixioverlay.
i tray to add pixioverlay to project with simple example but i did not find any example for moving marker by pixi.
thanks

```
               var markerTexture = resources.marker.texture;
               var markerLatLng = [29,50];
               var marker = new PIXI.Sprite(markerTexture);
                marker.popup = L.popup({className: 'pixi-popup'})
                .setLatLng(markerLatLng)
                .setContent('<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.')
                .openOn(map);
```